# Will we go down with the number of questions each day?

Tags: discussion

Today, when I was looking in the Area 51, I found that the number of questions asked in this site seems to be 1 per day, which it says to be poor.

As I have noticed, SE will has removed sites from beta earlier due to low performance.

I don't mean to pump in low quality questions into the platform, I just wanted to know whether we will stand the crisis.

We need more people viewing the site and more genuine doubts and clarifications coming up everyday.

Hope we could contribute something towards it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have been involved with a few other beta site creations - and they all seem to get a question like this sooner or later.

It is normal for there to be a flurry of activity in the first few weeks of a site's life, then to see a dip as things settle. I would expect activity to pick up.

It is quality that drives the activity that drives graduation. It is true that not every beta gets to graduate and some remain in beta for a long time. I can't see The Powers That Be shutting this site down without a good run.

We have already overtaken 19 other sites for questions per day - These are statistics [available to all](http://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#newest).  There are several sites in that list with lower traffic than ours that have been existence very much longer.

We have a good core, we have good quality, if we keep building it, they will come.

Answer (score 6):

As Robert details in his [answer here](https://iot.meta.stackexchange.com/a/203/78), "*This is a a fully functional, launched site. It is not "in beta" as you've come to understand it the traditional software development model, or "in testing" or something that failed to "graduate".*"

So while we certainly don't have to be enthusiastic about currently falling *question per day* numbers Stack Exchange won't shut us down for that. As Chenmunka points out there are plenty of sites with even worse *question per day* numbers.

Moreover, the [relevant meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614/338924) defines closure criteria as follows (emphasis *not* mine):

> **If there's enough moderation for a public beta site to consistently remain free of spam, for flags to be cleared, and for our Be Nice policy to be upheld, your site will remain open.**

That part of the site is alive and well. We have active community moderation by close voters and flaggers and even with moderator vacation those flags are handled pretty quickly. To be clear, I'm no member of the Stack Exchange Community Team, but I don't see any danger of us being shut down anytime soon.

Are we next in line to get a shiny graduation design, ditch the *beta* in the title and get elections, no we're not. But, we're not dying here either. *So this is very much a place where people can spent effort in good questions and answers without the fear of them being deleted at anytime.*

> Hope we could contribute something towards it!

Well, we can. By asking good questions, providing good answers and promoting the site. Participate in meta like with this question to shape the site to be a better version of itself. If you know somebody who might be interested point them here. If you have a platform, share a good question from this site. If you've got another good idea, go for it.

Answer (score 5):

Activity seems to be kind of level - we get good views, but not so many questions now. As a new field, its not unreasonable that we take time to grow - particularly since there is some overlap with existing sites (different ones depending on the questions). What will help is more **good** questions, more experts in the field, and more views.

So to help, share the best questions you find with your other networks, and ask good questions here.